# SharePoint alerts on changes

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-alerts

Is it possible to set up an alert to be notified whenever a single page changes in SharePoint? Not for every page but for a particular one in the pages library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an alert for a single page:

1. Go to the pages library.
2. Select the page for which you want to get an alert.
3. From the list of options for the library, select the ...
   (ellipses), and then select Alert Me.
4. In the Alert me when items change dialog, select and change the
   options you want.
5. To save, select OK.

[Create an alert to get notified when a file or folder changes in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/office/create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-sharepoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918)